# Journey builder, best practices in marketing cloud post journey completion

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, journeybuilder, automationstudio

What are the best practices for a journey, post completion in marketing cloud. In marketing cloud, once a journey is complete i.e. all communications have been delivered, tracking is available and contacts have exited the journey, journey status still shows running.

1. Does such multiple journeys on same data extension impacts marketing cloud performance ? (Performance in terms of speed of execution and system load)
2. Shall we manually stop each journey once it's complete ?
3. Should there be an option which automatically stops journey once it's complete or should there be an option to specify (date time limit) which stops journey at specified date & time ?

Answer (score 1):

1: You should be able to execute multiple journeys that reference the same data extension with relative ease, but once your data extension gets into the millions of rows it may impact performance, but it should not impact the entire system. I have noticed that numerous API calls to the same system objects can impact performance as well, so be careful if your journeys have "update contact" activities in them that are reaching out to large, shared data extensions.

2/3: There are only two ways to stop a journey currently: manually, [and using the API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/postStopInteractionById.htm).

Comment: Should we stop a journey manually once it's completed, in that case (big data and multiple journeys on same data extension) ?

Comment: It depends on how you decided to begin the journey. If the journey runs when new data is added to a data extension then yes if it's complete it would be safe to stop to avoid any accidental entries. If it was a "run once" journey it's safe to keep running however, I'd recommend turning those off as well since it makes it easier for you to filter for "active journeys" in your journey folder view.

Answer (score 0):

You can also find best practices in the [Help](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_bp_journey_builder_best_practices.htm&type=5) page.